# Google apps script Encryption API

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, encryption

I am trying to build An api with google apps script which can encrypt and decrypt strings. Below is my code:

```
function doPost(e){
  const body = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);//your probably want JSON.parse here instead of stringify
  const FlemishGiant = body.FlemishGiant;
  const NetherlandDwarf = body.NetherlandDwarf;
  const key = "$9681$%^&d";
  const cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(key, 'aes');
  if (body.includes("FlemishGiant")) {
    var encryptedMessage = cipher.encrypt(FlemishGiant);
    var json = {
    'rabbitname':encryptedMessage,
}; 
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); 

}
  if (body.includes("NetherlandDwarf")) {
   const decryptedMessage = cipher.decrypt(NetherlandDwarf);
    Logger.log(decryptedMessage);
    var json1 = {
      'rabbittype': decryptedMessage
  }; 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json1)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
else{
  return(error)
}

}
```

So when you send the API request The Encryption uses this type of Body:

```
{
"FlemishGiant":"STRING GOES HERE"
}
```

And the Decryption uses this body:

```
{
"NetherlandDwarf":"STRING GOES HERE"
}
```

My google apps script uses the cCryptoGS library.

I am having a problem with the Decryption mainly. I want the decrypted to be returned. When I try some things, it returns nothing, other times it gives me a typeerror saying that it cannot read property "NetherlandDwarf" of undefined, which NetherlandDwarf is a property of body.

Thanks so much And I hope we can find an answer soon!

Comment: Try putting `Logger.log(body);` after `const body = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents)` and check exections

Comment: That didn't work, I don't understand how that would even change anything.

Comment: It's a debugging tool.  The error indicates that body is not defined.  Was it?

Comment: If you trying to call doPost() from another function and your not supply the event object then that wont work.  doPost and doGet are functions that are call from deployed webapp endpoints.

Comment: the body is defined, the flemish giant (encryption) works perfectly.

Comment: That doesn't agree with the error and errors are not wrong very often

Comment: Perhaps this is where the error is occuring `const NetherlandDwarf = body.NetherlandDwarf;`  How id NetherlandDwarf become a property of body? Body is just a string.

Comment: Obviously I don't know what e.postData.contents is but did you mean this `JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents)` to be JSON.parse

Comment: No, I want it as a string I can read. NetherlandDwarf should be a property of it however. I use the same format as the flemishgiant endpoint, but use a different string

Comment: If it's a string the what is this declaration doing `const FlemishGiant = body.FlemishGiant;` I never heard of a string having that sort of property

Comment: that is a variable. What i am saying is that in the request body, both are formatted the same, except the JSON object is different, and the string type is different.

Comment: What is Logger.log(e.postData.contents)?